# How to know which array element is present in my database array?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to write a query in mongoDB where I want to find which elements of my array are present in database array 'upvotes' my query is given below

```
userupvotesmodel.findOne({mobile_no: "1234567890", upvotes : { $in : ["aa", "bdnvh", "563fa4408d88ea6c13c7abba", "djfufhgj", "5625bd9dbe545d2412d4ae62", "fjjshddhjfn", "djfhudh", "jfhshnffj", "sjdhfkskajdk"] } }, function(err, docs) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log('Error Finding query results');
                                    console.log(err);
                                    res.json({success: 0, message : err});
                                    return next(err);
                                } else {
                                    if (docs) {
                                        console.log('2 mins', currentdate.getMinutes());
                                        console.log('2 secs', currentdate.getSeconds());
                                        console.log('docs', docs);
                                    }
                                }
});
```

Now for query above if any single value of my array is present in database then it sends whole upvotes array but I am not able to find out which elements were present for e.g "aa", "bdnvh" etc in database how can I write a query to know which elements are present in the database.

I want to find this in one query by querying for every single element; I know I can do this but I want to do this in any possible single mongoDB query.

Comment: What about map-reduce?

Comment: @stdob-- can you please provide me any link for using map-reduce here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to worry about the query and you can just use java script instead. Just iterate through the docs.upvotes array and compare its values with the array you provided.

```js
var my_array = ["aa", "bdnvh", "563fa4408d88ea6c13c7abba", "djfufhgj", "5625bd9dbe545d2412d4ae62", "fjjshddhjfn", "djfhudh", "jfhshnffj", "sjdhfkskajdk"];

// ... your code

// inside of if(docs) statement
var matched_elements = [];
docs.upvotes.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
    if (my_array[i] == element) {
      matched_elements.push(element);
    }
  }
});
console.log(matched_elements);
```

Comment: yea actually i am using same approach and i am also implementing binary search to reduce the time, but actually i was thinking that as my upvotes array will contain 1000 of strings, will there be any problem retrieving this data from mongo to server that's why i was thinking about using a single query by which i don't have to fetch all upvotes array data on the server side.

Comment: I posted below a solution with aggregation framework. To read more on it go to: [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/)

Comment: can you please tell me this is this approach usable or should i use aggregate one i mean is this a proper way or aggregate one is ??

Comment: @amanverma hey, do you mean you just want to get one document? If so make the $match query more specific ie. add "mobile_no": "1234567890"

Comment: no i am just asking that among your two answers i was using first one thats why i am  just asking among both approaches what do u think most developers will choose which approach (first one where fetch all upvotes array data OR second one using aggregation) ??

Comment: @amanverma I think aggregation is actually better. But your choice should depend on wheter you want more workload done on the database side (aggregation) or  server side (iteration).

Comment: no it is not working alan can you please help me out here ??

Answer (score 1):

You could use the aggregation framework. First $unwind your upvotes array. Then $match on elements that are in the array provided by you. Than $group it back on _id(or whatever you want) creating "matched_elements" array with $addToSet or $push. The returned documents will have only upvotes elements (in "matched_elements array) that are also in your array.

```js
var my_array = ["aa", "bdnvh", "563fa4408d88ea6c13c7abba", "djfufhgj", "5625bd9dbe545d2412d4ae62", "fjjshddhjfn", "djfhudh", "jfhshnffj", "sjdhfkskajdk"];

db.collection.aggregate( [ 
  { "$unwind" : "$upvotes" }, 
  { "$match": { "upvotes": {"$in": my_array} } },
  { "$group" : { "_id":"$_id","matched_elements":{ "$addToSet": "$upvotes" }}}
] );
```

Comment: i am using this query in mongoose but it is not returning anything in result even if i have one element in my_array present in upvotes aray can you please help me out why it is not running ??

Comment: userfavouritemodel.aggregate([
              { "$match": { "upvotes": {"$in": my_array}, "mobile_no":"1234567890" } },
              { $unwind: "$upvotes" },
              { "$group" : { "_id":"$_id","matched_elements":{ "$addToSet": "$upvotes" }}}
              ], function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return;
                }
                console.log('user favourites');
                console.log(result);
              });

Comment: are you there @alan ?? pls help me ??

Comment: no it is not working alan can you please help me out here ??